# Please guide me for the muenchian grouping based on attribute value using xslt1.0

Tags: xslt

I want to group the element using muenchian grouping  . I am using xslt 1.0 Could you pleae guide me..

xml is like below..

```
<responseDA xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org">
<outputData>   
<dictionary id="AutoOutputs"> 

<list numOfItems="2">       
<item>       
<field dataType="double" name="DOWNPAYMENT">2000.00</field>
</item>     
<item>       
<field dataType="double" name="DOWNPAYMENT">3000.00</field>
</item>
</list>  
<list numOfItems="2">       
<item>       
<field dataType="string" name="CAMPAIGNCODE">A</field>\
</item>
<item>       
<field dataType="string" name="CAMPAIGNCODE">B</field>
</item>
</list>   
<list numOfItems="2">       
<item>      
<field dataType="double" name="BALLOONPAYMENT">4000.00</field>
</item>
<item>       
<field dataType="double" name="BALLOONPAYMENT">5000.00</field>
</item>
</list>       
</dictionary>
</outputData>
</responseDA>
```

Now I need to group the campaign based on the "numofitems" in the attribute of list.
Output should be..

```
 <Campaigns>
    <campaignNumber>A</ns:campaignNumber>
    <downPayment>2000.00</ns:downPayment>
    <ballonPayment>4000.00</ns:ballonPayment>
    </Campaigns>
    <Campaigns>
    <campaignNumber>B</ns:campaignNumber>
    <downPayment>3000.00</ns:downPayment>
    <ballonPayment>5000.00</ns:ballonPayment>
    </Campaigns>
```

I have tried but it is not working...

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="responseDA" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="camp" match="//list/@numOfItems" use="field" />

<xsl:template match="responseDA">       
<xsl:for-each  select="list/@numOfItems[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key(&apos;camp&apos;,field)[1])]">
<Campaigns>
<campaignNumber>
<xsl:value-of select="item/field[@name=&apos;CAMPAIGNCODE&apos;]" />
</campaignNumber>
<xsl:for-each xmltem="http://tempuri.org" select="key(&apos;camp&apos;,field)">
<downPayment>
<xsl:value-of select="item/field[@name=&apos;DOWNPAYMENT&apos;]" />
</downPayment>
<ballonPayment>
<xsl:value-of select="item/field[@name=&apos;BALLOONPAYMENT&apos;]" />
</ballonPayment>
</xsl:for-each>
</Campaigns>
</xsl:for-each>     
</xsl:template>
```

Please correct me where  I am doing wrong...

regards,
Inian

Comment: Could you please check now .. I have attached my code. Are you able to see my code?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look to me like a problem that requires Muenchian grouping. You simply want to create one output "row" for each `item` in (any one of) the lists, with values taken from the corresponding *positions* in the other lists:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//list[1]/item"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:variable name="mypos" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="fields" select="//list/item[$mypos]/field"/>
    <Campaigns>
      <campaignNumber>
        <xsl:value-of select="$fields[@name='CAMPAIGNCODE']"/>
      </campaignNumber>
      <downPayment>
        <xsl:value-of select="$fields[@name='DOWNPAYMENT']"/>
      </downPayment>
      <ballonPayment>
        <xsl:value-of select="$fields[@name='BALLOONPAYMENT']"/>
      </ballonPayment>
    </Campaigns>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input XML this produces the output you requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <Campaigns>
    <campaignNumber>A</campaignNumber>
    <downPayment>2000.00</downPayment>
    <ballonPayment>4000.00</ballonPayment>
  </Campaigns>
  <Campaigns>
    <campaignNumber>B</campaignNumber>
    <downPayment>3000.00</downPayment>
    <ballonPayment>5000.00</ballonPayment>
  </Campaigns>
</root>
```

(wrapped in a single root-level element in order to make it well-formed XML).

You say in a comment that you need to "sort the campaigns" - you can sort at the point where you `apply-templates`, remembering that the template rule I give above doesn't care *which* row's items it is processing, only that it processes all the items from the same row.

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//list[item/field/@name = 'CAMPAIGNCODE']/item">
        <xsl:sort select="field" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
```

but you will also need to change the definition of the `mypos` variable:

```
  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:variable name="mypos" select="count(preceding-sibling::item) + 1"/>
```

since `position()` will now give you the position in *sorted* order, whereas you require the position in the original document order.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response but it is not working as expected. It is returning only one campaignumber. I am trying to loop the entire list multiple time..

Comment: @user3553819 it works for me based on the XML sample you posted in the question, but the presence of the (not well-formed) `ns:` in some of the tags of your "required output" suggests that this question is not quite an accurate reflection of your real data.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ian Roberts.. U saved my day. It is working. One small concern is now based on downpayment i need to sort the campaigns..

Comment: @user3553819 I've edited with some ideas on how you could adapt the stylesheet for this.